# IllegalArgumentException when trying to get reference to Field using Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, illegalargumentexception

I am trying to loop through many ArrayLists of custom classes with the same code and thought using reflection would make it easier. I am running into an issue when I try to get a reference to each field however. Here is a small representation of the code I am trying to run. (my code is different but the essentials are there):

```
    import java.lang.reflect.*;
    import java.util.ArrayList;


    public class Stack {

        public ArrayList<Custom1> cust11;
        public ArrayList<Custom1> cust12;
        public ArrayList<Custom1> cust13;
        public ArrayList<Custom2> cust21;
        public ArrayList<Custom2> cust22;
        public ArrayList<Custom2> cust23;
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            Stack stack = new Stack();
        }

        public Stack() {
            cust11 = new ArrayList<Custom1>();
            cust12 = new ArrayList<Custom1>();
            cust13 = new ArrayList<Custom1>();
            cust21 = new ArrayList<Custom2>();
            cust22 = new ArrayList<Custom2>();
            cust23 = new ArrayList<Custom2>();

            doReflect();
        }

        public void doReflect(){
            Field[] fields = this.getClass().getFields();
            for(Field f : fields) {
                if(f.getName().contains("cust1")) {
                    try {
                        ArrayList<Custom1> temp = (ArrayList<Custom1>)f.get(cust11);

                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Custom1{
        public Custom1() {}
    }

    class Custom2{
        public Custom2() {}
    }
```

When it gets to

```
ArrayList<Custom1> temp = (ArrayList<Custom1>)f.get(cust11);
```

I get

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.util.ArrayList field 
Stack.cust11 to java.util.ArrayList
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Unknown Source)
at Stack.doReflect(Stack.java:33)
at Stack.<init>(Stack.java:25)
at Stack.main(Stack.java:14)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You're iterating fields of your class `Stack` *(`this.getClass().getFields()`)*, but giving the `Field.get` method an `ArrayList` instance *(`cust11`)*. Perhaps you meant to call `f.get(this)`?

Comment: thank you. That's what I was missing

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. Reflection does not make this easier. It makes this inefficient and error-prone. And keep in mind that the order of the fields returned by `Class.getFields()` is not guaranteed. As [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getFields()) states: “*The elements in the returned array are not sorted and are not in any particular order*”

Comment: In my case I don't care about innefficiency. I just didn't want to have 8 for loop all doing the same thing but with different variables. Reflection shortened my code which is all I cared about. Also, I filter my field names as I iterate through them so order doesn't mattter

Answer (score 1):

I should have used

```
ArrayList<Custom1> temp = (ArrayList<Custom1>)f.get(this);
```